# Editing page in Django

Tags: python, django

im new to python and django (as you can probably tell).

Im following cs50 web course and im trying to let user edit a page's current title and content. Problem is, the current content is not being displayed.

We are not working with databases or sessions yet.
An entry is basically title + content on whatever topic.

form.py:

```
from django import forms

class NewEntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title", required=True, max_length=100)
    content = forms.CharField(label="Content", widget=forms.Textarea, required=True, max_length=1000)
```

views.py, where its not working:

```
def edit_entry(request, title):
    try:
        content = util.get_entry(title)  #store content of the entry
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Page not found")

    form = NewEntryForm()
    form.content = content 

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/new_entry.html", {
        "form": form,  #to create the displayed form
        "form.content": form.content, "form.title": title,  #to fill the form with the stored info
        "title": title.capitalize(), "messages": None,  #page title & warning messages
    })
```

same template for creating and editing an entry:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% if messages %}
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    {{ messages }}
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="content-section" style=" margin: auto; width: 50%; padding: 10px;">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit_entry' title%}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title.label }}
        {{ form.title }}
        {{ form.content.label}}
        {{ form.content }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

util.py:

```
def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Comment: add an `action` in your form tag not href and you are calling `{% url 'new_entry' %}` and your view is doing an edit. Don't you think you are calling an incorrect view?

Comment: @Subham oh boy, youre right. I was so focused on views.py, thanks. I edited the post. The problem persists tho, form.content at views.py does store the info, but its not being passed.

Comment: @subham also one little question, why not href but action? they seem to be doing the same thing